# How to add INotifyPropertyChanged to classes containing generic types?

Tags: c#, wpf, generics

WPF C# Generics

I am very new to generics. I am *attempting* to make an Editor for entities with private setters as:

```
public class EditorBase<T>  where T: class, new() 
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
}



public class AccountEditor<T> :  EditorBase<T> where T : class, new()
    {
        public AccountEditor()
        {
            bR = new BillingRepository();
            pt = new ViewPatient();
        }

        public viewName Name { get; private set; }
        public ViewPatient pt { get; private set; }

        public virtual async void SetAccountAsync(viewName _name)
        {
            Name = _name;
            if (_name == null)
                pt = new ViewPatient();
            else
            {
                pt = await bR.GetPersonByNameAsync(_name.lastName, _name.firstName, DateTime.Parse(_name.birthDate));
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }


        private readonly BillingRepository bR;

        private string _mi;
        public string mi
        {
            get { return pt.mi; }
            set { if (pt.mi == value) return; pt.SetMi(value); RaisePropertyChanged(); }
}
```

Rather then the entities immplementing INotifyPropertyChanged, I am using an
Editor for binding. My problem is the syntax to add an interface to the 
editor class.

**How to I add the interface INotifyPropertyChanged to the class EditorBase declaration?**

This syntax fails:
EditorBase where T: class, new() : INotifyPropertyChanged

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried  `public class EditorBase<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged where T : class, new()`

Comment: @Daniel Great! That worked. So simple. I must have missed the documentation for this. (I tried for two days trying different things!). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This syntax fails: EditorBase where T: class, new() : INotifyPropertyChanged

The correct syntax is `EditorBase<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged where T:class, new()`

> Since the entities have private setters, they can not implement INotifyPropertyChanged themselves

I honestly have no clue what you mean by that. Any class can declare that it implements any interface or not, regardless of what visibility its property setters use.

Comment: Though I see no need for the classifiers on `T` on the base class. Or for `T` in general. The base class does nothing with it, it shouldn't be there.

Comment: Sorry...what I meant was that each entity has a private setter, so I can't figure out how to directly bind the XAML to a property with a private setter. If this can be done, it would sure make things easier.  Suggestions?

Comment: You absolutely can bind to read-only properties (which is what you have there). They'll just be one-way bindings.

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: "I see no need for the classifiers on T". I am at the beginning of a very long process that will use T. I believe it will be used down the line. Time will tell. Thanks.